# RTC: Resolving stream gaps?

Tags: rtc, ibm-rational

I have a file in RTC (call it `foo.c`) that I modified and checked into a changeset (`CS1`) along with some other changes.  I then modified that file again and checked it into a different changeset (`CS2`) along with other changes.

I've now run into a case where I want to deliver `CS2` to a stream, but RTC is giving me an error that delivering that would create a gap in the stream (because of the change in `CS1`).  I don't want to deliver all of `CS1` yet, because it contains some changes that shouldn't be in a build yet.  The original change to `foo.c` in `CS1` was a minor removal of a `#include`, and doesn't affect anything else.

Is there any way to resolve that gap?

I see some stuff in the RTC documentation about applying patches, but I don't understand where it's going with that.
Is there a way to split a changeset into multiple changesets, which would allow me just to deliver the one file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update since 2012 (and the original "workaround" of delivering everything and reverting what you don't want):

See [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/129692/delivering-these-changes-would-introduce-gaps):

> In RTC 4.0.5 we delivered additional support when trying to accept change sets which have a gap (often encountered when trying to backport fixes).
>
> In a very brief summary of the feature, when you accept change sets with a gap, you can now follow a gap workflow that accepts one change set at a time and, for change sets that contain gaps, creates a new change set (with aided traceability), that contains the equivalent changes.
>   This means users will not have to accept the change sets 'as a patch'.
>
> Applying change sets as a patch has limitations compared to the new workflow.
>   This feature is summarized in the [RTC 4.0.5 'New & Noteworthy' page](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/4.0.5?p=news#scm-improve-usability-405-m1).
>
> Below are some videos which show this feature:
>
> - [Accepting multiple change sets with gaps in the RTC 4.0.5 client for Eclipse IDE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28raag5RdzU)
> - [Accepting a change set with a gap in the RTC 4.0.5 client for Eclipse IDE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TucVu_BgB7E)

That is the [Locate Change Sets](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyX32R7da2c) feature:

[image: https://jazz.net/downloads/pages/rational-team-concert/4.0.5/4.0.5/images/gapeditor.png]

---

> In RTC 5.0 we added a "fill the gap" feature where the change sets that fill the gap are shown to the user, allowing them to either accept all the change sets or to continue with the gap workflow that was available in RTC 4.0.5.
>
> This feature is summarized in the [RTC 5.0 'New & Noteworthy' page](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/5.0?p=news#eclipse-fill-gaps):
>
> The classes that are involved for filling the gap include (available in RTC 5.0):
>
> ```
> client side: IWorkspaceConnection.findChangeSetsToAcceptToFillGap(...) 
> server side: IScmQueryService.findChangeSetsToAcceptToFillGap(...)
> ```
>
> Both features are explained in detail in the "[Improved Gap Handling for SCM](https://jazz.net/library/article/1372)" article.

[image: https://jazz.net/downloads/pages/rational-team-concert/5.0/5.0/images/missing-change-sets-dialog.png]

---

Original answer (2012)

> Is there a way to split a changeset?

I don't think so, reading the [changeset man page](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/c_csets.html&re=1&scope=null):

> A file or folder in a component cannot be part of more than one active change set.
>   When a file or folder is included in an active change set, all changes to it become part of that change set whether or not the change set is current, and **changes to that file or folder cannot be explicitly checked in to a new change set until the active change set that includes it is completed**.

Having foo.c in CS1 *and* CS2 means CS1 has been "completed" (frozen, in essence), and it would be bad to try and split it.

The patch solution means:

- cancelling CS1
- adding the additional change to foo.c to CS2
- redoing CS1 changes

See "[How do I remove a change set from a stream?](https://jazz.net/library/article/126#How_do_I_remove_a_change_set_fro)"

[Story 149483](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=149483) is about enhancing that cumbersome workflow, and the gap detection is being enhanced ([Enhancement 24822](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=24822))

---

The [OP timwoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402834/timwoj) concludes:

> **I ended up just delivering all of it, then reversing the one that I didn't want**.

Comment: Part of my problem is that other changesets have been checked in after CS1 and CS2, making both of them completed.  If I create a patch reversing CS1, merge it into my workspace, and try to deliver it, I just get yet another error saying that delivering it would create a gap.

Comment: @timwoj seems normal: you would need to deliver that patch along with `CS1` (if it it still there), `CS2`, `CS3`,... up until `CSpatch` included (which cancels `CS1`), in order to ensure no gap.

Comment: I ended up just delivering all of it, then reversing the one that I didn't want.  Thank your for the links, they were much more helpful than the little bit in the docs about gaps.

Comment: @timwoj that is one way to resolve the issue. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

Problem: CS1 changes foo.c, CS2 further changes foo.c.  You only want to deliver CS2, but RTC tells you that would introduce gaps.

Solution: Create a patch from CS2 and suspend both CS1 and CS2.  Then apply the patch, merge it into your workspace and check-in the changes which will create yet another change set, CS3, identical to CS2 but with no dependency on CS1. You can now deliver CS3.

After delivering CS3, you can discard CS2 and resume CS1 which will require you to merge with CS3.

Then you should be in the state that CS1 builds on CS3 and you can choose whether or not to deliver CS1 in the future.

Comment: +1. I didn't try discarding changeSet before applying the patch and delivering the new changeset. The discard bit might have been the missing step here.